# How is the diameter of this graph equal to 6

Tags: graph-theory

I am considering the following graph

[image]

However, I fail to see how this graph has a diameter of 6.

I calculated all the eccentricities of the vertices, and I got 3, 4, and 5. So I see how the radius of the graph is 3, but I don't see how the diameter is 6. In fact, I don't even think it's possible if we look at the definition which is founded on the definition of the length of a path, and that depends on edges. The longest path is 5, so I don't see how the largest eccentricity can be greater than 5.  Where am I going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distance $d(u,v)$ between two vertices $u$ and $v$ of a finite graph is the minimum length of the paths connecting them.

The first node needs to travel $6$ edges to reach the last node.

Comment: Thank you! I just checked where I went wrong and I did not draw the graph correctly...I have six vertices. I appreciate your time